# How to insert element before each element with new data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div id="elem">
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <div data-foo="bbb"></div>
    <div data-foo="bbb"></div>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
</div>
```

I need to insert an `h1` before the first new different attribute, like this:

```
<div id="elem">
    <h1>aaa</h1>
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <div data-foo="aaa"></div>
    <h1>bbb</h1>
    <div data-foo="bbb"></div>
    <div data-foo="bbb"></div>
    <h1>ccc</h1>
    <div data-foo="ccc"></div>
    .
    .
```

Those elements are dynamically inserted, but they are aways in order.
Could somebody please help me?

Comment: please add your javascript code here

Answer (score 5):

Try using `.before()` in this context whenever the data-foo gets changed,

```
var temp = "";
var foo = "";

$('#elem [data-foo]').each(function(){
  foo = $(this).data('foo');
  if(temp !== foo){
    $(this).before('<h1>'+ foo +'</h1>');
    temp = foo;
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7nxF/)

---

### Your Sub - Question 1:

## *How can I add a div after every four foo divs?*

```
var count = 0;

$('#elem [data-foo]').each(function(){
    count += 1;
  if(count === 4){
    $(this).after('<div>New div</div>');
    count = 0;
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7nxF/)

Comment: how to view top users?

Comment: Thanks dude! By the way I have another question.. How can I add a div after every four foo divs?

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos That must be an interesting question and it would be helpful for future referrers too, Post that as a new one so that you can get more expert's eye on that.. And link me to that question if you wish.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$ (document).ready(function() 
    { PrevAttr= '';
        $('div#elem div').each(function(){

            attr = $(this).attr('data-foo');

            if(attr != PrevAttr)
            { PrevAttr = attr;
              $('<h1>'+attr+'</h1>').insertBefore(this);
            }
        })
})
```

**Your Sub - Question 1:
How can I add a div after every four foo divs?**

You can do it simply

```
$('#elem [data-foo]:nth-child(4n)').after('<div class="test"></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that doesn't involve jQuery:

```
function insertHeaders(element) {
    var lastAttribute = '';     
    var children = element.children;
    var length = children.length;

    for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        var currentAttribute = child.getAttribute('data-foo');
        if(currentAttribute !== lastAttribute) {
            var header = document.createElement('h1');
            header.innerHTML = currentAttribute;
            element.insertBefore(header, child);
        }

        lastAttribute = currentAttribute;
    }
}

var container = document.getElementById('elem');
insertHeaders(container);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vAwj2/)

Comment: is it possible to wrap every different `div[data-foo]` inside a div for each group?